# group by и annotate в django

Tags: orm, django

Привет всем. Поискав, узнал что group_by нету в django, удивило, почему? Нашел, то что можно подобное сделать через annotate. Написал через annotate, но он выводит лишнее поле. Вообще задача состоит вот в чем, есть модель.

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    id_schedule = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    date = models.DateField(editable = False,verbose_name=u'дата')
```

Пример данных, которые хранятся в ней:

```
1 | 2012-05-28
2 | 2012-05-28
3 | 2012-05-19
4 | 2012-05-19
5 | 2012-05-19
6 | 2012-05-26
```

В итоге мне нужно получить:

```
5 | 2012-05-19
6 | 2012-05-26
2 | 2012-05-28
```

Я написал запрос

```
schedules =  Schedule.objects.filter(date__gte = date).order_by('date', '-       id_schedule').annotate(Count('date'))
```

но в запросе есть почему то

GROUP BY "schedule_schedule"."id _ schedule",

Почему такое происходит? Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Если с ходу не выходит — я бы не стал бодаться с джанговским ORMом и сказал [`Schedule.objects.raw("...")`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). Мучаться с инструментом ради неизвестной выгоды — сомнительное удовольствие.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `values()`, потому что `orm` по умолчанию будет всегда включать `id`, соответственно ни `distinct`, ни `GROUP BY` работать не будут.

```
schedules =  Schedule.objects.values('date').filter(date__gte=date).
                      order_by('date').annotate(count=Count('date'))
```

**UPDATE**

Если нужны последние `id`'шники, то можно получить их функцией `max()` т.е. получится что-то вроде

```
schedules =  Schedule.objects.filter(date__gte=date).order_by('date')
                     .annotate(id=Max('id'), count=Count('date'))
```

если я ничего не перепутал.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, но мне нужны id_schedules, как в примере выше я написал.

Comment: Я с трудом представляю как это сделать средствами SQL. Не говоря уже о Django ORM. Хотя.... сейчас покумекаю.

Answer (score 2):

Привет, а то что нужно получить разве не distinct'ом делается обычно?

```
schedules =  Schedule.objects.filter(date__gte = date).order_by('date', '-       id_schedule').distinct('date')
```

вот дока https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Да,я это читал и пробовал, но не работает и не пойму почему. Вот sql который получается

    SELECT DISTINCT "schedule_schedule"."id_schedule", "schedule_schedule"."date" FROM "schedule_schedule" WHERE "schedule_schedule"."date" >= 2012-05-14  ORDER BY "schedule_schedule"."date" ASC, "schedule_schedule"."id_schedule" DESC

Все вроде как надо, но выводит вот что
5 2012-05-19
4 2012-05-19
3 2012-05-19
7 2012-05-26
2 2012-05-28
1 2012-05-28

Comment: ну на первый взгляд запрос нормальный, должно работать. Проверь данные, там точно тип Date? Может DateTime и значения в базе все-таки разные?

Да, и попробуй временно убрать 
<pre>.filter(date__gte = date).order_by('date', '-id_schedule')</pre>

Comment: ``DISTINCT "schedule_schedule"."id_schedule"`` - даст все различные id, ничего удивительного. уберите из order_by его, тогда в селекте его тоже не будет, будет одна дата выводиться...

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужны id_schedules, вот как с ними выбрать?

Answer (score 0):

1. GROUP BY [есть](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)
2. Вам нужен [DISTINCT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct), смотрите примеры, там есть именно пример для вашего случая:

   Entry.objects.order_by('author', 'pub_date').distinct('author')